# What is the fastest way to get ipv4 from hostname

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, performance-testing

I know my question is a little weird but i didn't find an answer.

When it comes to performance which function is fastest to retrieve ipv4 only not ipv6 from a hostname

`gethostbyname()`
or
`gethostbyname_r()`
or
`getaddrinfo()`

and I have a little question about gethostbyname which one is better to copy h_addr to sockaddr_in

memcpy or bcopy or like that

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(unsigned long *) remoteHost->h_addr_list[0];
```

And when it comes to both of performance and thread safety ( not getting any crashes / problems in future )

`gethostbyname_r()`
Or
`getaddrinfo()`

and thanks.

I searched and googled it and did some benchmarks but i didn't get a definite answer and I need an expert have a good experience in c tell me what is better in his opinion as an expert

Comment: Just about the same no matter which function you use. If the hostname isn't cached locally there's going to be a DNS lookup which is going to make any other differences between the function so small as they're basically non-measurable.

Comment: Just test different DNS servers and configure your system to use the fastest server + comment above. There is nothing to optimize from code point of view, since here the IO operations are time critical part.